# Convert a string to date from json file

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I want to get data from a json file on order to populate a postgres spatial database.

in the json file, the date data is stored in : "dt_txt": "2016-05-21 03:00:00", and I want to store 2016-05-21 in date.

```
$json_d=file_get_contents('file.json);
$data=json_decode($json_d,TRUE);    
$date=$data['list'][0]['dt_txt'];
$dbconn = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost; port=5432; dbname=DB", "postgres", "0000");
$insertmbr = $dbconn->prepare("INSERT INTO weather(date) VALUES(?)");
$insertmbr->execute(array($date));
```

when i run the code this error appears

> Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert it to a timestamp first

`$date = strtotime($data['list'][0]['dt_txt']);`

Then you can use the `date` method to format it as desired:

`$date = date('Y-m-d', $date);`

You can also extract the time using the same command:

`$time = date('H:i:s', $date);`

Or, alternatively you could just split the string on the space using `explode`:

`list($date, $time) = explode(' ', $date, 2);`

Comment: thank you very much, what about time? if I want to store 03:00:00 in another variable !

Comment: No problem, I have updated the answer with what you asked for, and also a method that is faster, using explode, but is less flexible. Note however it is usually a better idea to store the result of `strtotime` in the database as this is a unix timestamp and easier to manipulate.

Comment: I am very grateful, thanks again
it worked perfectly.